# How to find list of unique files that have changed

Tags: git

How can I get a unique list of files that have changed using git?  I'm looking specifically for modified or added files.

This command is not bad, but it's a bit too verbose - I don't care about which commit it was part of, and it's also not unique - if the same file was changed in multiple commits, it's listed twice.

```
git log --name-status --oneline
```

> - e5a7926 Change wording of test
>     | M     spec/entities/agent_evaluator_spec.rb
> - 7b2a81c Implement autosubstitution feature
>     | M     lib/scoring/entities/agent_evaluator.rb
>     | M     spec/entities/agent_evaluator_spec.rb
>     | M     spec/services/agent_evaluation_spec.rb
> - a5de237 Add unused_players to agent_evaluation specs
>     | M     spec/entities/agent_evaluator_spec.rb
>     | M     spec/services/agent_evaluation_spec.rb
>     | M     spec/support/factory_helpers.rb
> - 083757c Refactor agent service spec
>     | M     spec/services/agent_service_spec.rb
>     | M     spec/support/editor_service_stub.rb

I'm looking for something like this:

> spec/entities/agent_evaluator_spec.rb
>   lib/scoring/entities/agent_evaluator.rb
>   spec/services/agent_evaluation_spec.rb
>   spec/support/factory_helpers.rb
>   spec/services/agent_service_spec.rb
>   spec/support/editor_service_stub.rb
>   ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "changed".  What about a file that was added or deleted?  Do you care about rename detection?

Comment: added yes, deleted not really.  thanks for the clarification, will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to restrict git-log to just a list of all filenames ever changed without looking at commit history. However, you can certainly strip out the stuff you don't care about. For example:

```
git whatchanged --oneline --name-only |
    grep --extended-regexp --invert-match '^[[:xdigit:]]{7,}'
```

This will show the history, including the filenames changed in each commit, and then egrep will strip out all the commit IDs and commit summaries. This leaves you with just a list of filenames changed during each commit, without the attendant commit history.

Comment: That seems to be a lot more verbose than what the OP is looking for ? Are there any further options that would reduce the output to just the file names ?

Comment: that's nice.  thanks!  I threw `| head -n20` on the end, but works great :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [CodeGnome's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25289558/1256452) but slightly different:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only $more_options | grep . | sort -u
```

For `$more_options` you may want:

```
--diff-filter=M
```

or:

```
--diff-filter=AM --no-renames
```

or something along those lines.  The `--diff-filter` uses the status that you'd see with `--name-status` to inhibit or include specific entries.  (See the [`git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) for details.)  Because this outputs blank lines for the log messages even with `--pretty=format:` (an empty format), we throw in `grep .` to take only lines with at least one character, then we run the resulting file names through `sort -u` to get a `uniq`-ed result.